# Dice Probability question

Tags: probability

The question is,

> When Six side dice rolled until the first time T that a four turns up.
>   What is the Sample space for T and distribution function?
>   Also, What is the probability T>3?

I thought sample space is S={ 1,2,3,4,5,6 } and distribution is uniformly 1/6.
Am I wrong ? is it S = { 1,2,3,4,5,6, 11,12,13,14,15,16,21,22,23 ...,  }?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose you roll the six-sided die several times and you get $5$, then $2$, then $1$, then $2$, then $6$, then $3$, then $5$, then $4$. Then in this case we observe that $t=8$. Indeed, $T$ can be any positive integer.

To figure out its distribution, assume that each roll is independent. To find the probability that $T=t$, find the probability that the first $t-1$ rolls are not a four, but the last roll (the $t^{\text{th}}$ roll) is a four.

Answer (score 0):

Although I know many people, including lecturers, who would think of the sample space as  $S=\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,\ldots\}$ (the range of $T$), I think a sample space that provides a more complete description of the experiment is the space $S'=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^{\mathbb N}$, ie. the space of all infinite lists $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$ where each $a_i$ is a whole number between 1 and 6. You can think of each such list as the result of rolling a die an infinite number of times. The random variable $T$ then takes such a list and returns the least $t$ such that $a_t=4$. For example, $T((1,3,4,6,6,6,\ldots))=3$.

This utility of this interpretation becomes apparent when we wish to construct other random variables that have some relation to $T$, for example $U$, the sum of the results of rolling a die before the first four turns up. Given an element $\ell=(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)\in S'$,
\begin{equation*} U(\ell)=\sum^{T(\ell)-1}_{i=1}a_i. \end{equation*}
It is impossible to construct this function on the sample space $S$, even though we are performing the same experiment (rolling a die until we get a 4).